# Seaborn Color Palette not working appropiate with lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn, color-palette

I'm having a little trouble with customizing my colors for a lineplot. I want to show an ensemble of spectras with a sequential color palette. The argument "palette="blues" works fine, but does not accept any appropriate color lists (like "Blues_d"), which do not include any bright colors.

[image: This is a representative graph showing how my plot looks like]

Below you can see the code I'm using.

```
color = (sns.dark_palette("purple"))
sns.set()

ax = sns.lineplot(x="Wavelength", y="Absorption", hue="t (min)", lw=1, data=df1, palette=color, legend="brief")
```

The problem is, that I get the following error:

> ValueError: The palette list has the wrong number of colors.

So the question is: How can I use the lineplot function and using a sequential color palette of blues, reds, or whatever that do not include any bright colors?

I'm using pandas version 0.23.3, matplotlib version 2.2.2 and seaborn version 0.9.0

Comment: Honestly, why can't it do this by itself, checking that the number of different series wanting plots is less than the number of colours provided instead of having an exact match

Comment: @ifly6 'cause matplotlib and seaborn have become a mess :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since you mention the `t (min)` column in the `hue` option, you need to know the total number of unique values of the column.

Assume that there are 5 unique values in the column. You, thus, can set the number to the `n_colors` option of `sns.color_palette`:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Wavelength", 
                  y="Absorption", 
                  hue="t (min)", 
                  lw=1, 
                  data=df1, 
                  palette=sns.color_palette('coolwarm', n_colors=5), 
                  legend="brief")
```

Comment: This solution will not yield the intended result. Suppose your unique `t (min)` values are 1, 2 and 100. The items with value 2 will receive the middle hue, rather than the low hue.

Answer (score 5):

No need to worry about the color count if you set your color palette as a color map by setting "as_cmap" argument to True in sns.color_palette:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Wavelength", 
                      y="Absorption", 
                      hue="t (min)", 
                      lw=1, 
                      data=df1, 
                      palette=sns.color_palette('coolwarm', as_cmap = True), 
                      legend="brief")
```

Comment: I think most people coming to this question would be helped by this answer. Thank you.

Comment: if you aren't directly writing to the ax object this approach fails: `sns.lineplot(data=out_df, x="lag", y="rse", hue="period", palette=sns.color_palette('coolwarm', as_cmap = True))` generates TypeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object is not iterable - the above approach works fine

Comment: @MStoner I don't understand your comment. What "above approach" works fine?

Comment: The approach of setting ncolors as per Hakan Özler's comment. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

```
Palette = ["#090364", "#091e75"] #define your preference
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_palette(Palette) #use the list defined in the function
plot = sns.countplot(df['Purchased']) #Enjoy ploting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in other way `sns.pairplot(data,hue='catagorical_variable',pallete='Set1)`
Because the seaborn also have it's predefined sets of colors.